# Get all promotions applied on Product

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

We have 1 Api, which sends product code in request and in result we need to pass all promotions related to that product with promotion message and priority. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to find your solution. Promotions applied to cart, instead of product. Promotions saved as a xml file. You need to parse to analyze it. On the other hand promotions not related product directly, sometimes promotions related with product category, date, customer, etc.